# Choices.js search on disabled options

Tags: javascript, choices.js

I have a choices.js single with some options disabled. I want the text search return also results of disabled options.
Any ideas to do it ?
(I use fuseOptions, but maybe it's filtered before call fuse)

Comment: Not sure what the purpose of that would be in the first place - does "disabled" not also mean, that I won't be able to actually _chose_ the found item then? Either way, I don't think any of the fuseOptions settings will help you here - those won't change what fuse gets passed as data to search _in_, I suppose. Maybe you could enable all options when the `search` fires, and disable the ones that should be disabled after, when the user has actually made a choice.

Comment: thanks for the answer, you have an idea how to have a hook on search to remove disabled options and hook after to set disabled after search ?
I have to do this because user have to see the results of options he can't select, because I precise the reason on the option label "disabled because...". It's for an Inventory in an App, all the products have to be displayed and some cannot be selected but user have to see them and know why. (sorry for my english)

Comment: That was just a vague guess what you could try, but I don't know the details of how this library works - whether it would even gather the options every single time the filter functionality is triggered, or whether it only goes over them once, when it initializes itself. (If the latter was the case, then you could probably simply work around the problem by only disabling the options _after_ you let the library functionality initialize?)